# How can I create a 'pause' inside a loop in a web application so I don't 'hammer' an external service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a basic search which gives a list of results of html documents. You can click on those results and go to a page "view.aspx?id=xxxx" to see those html documents.

A feature on the results page is to "Compile all results into a PDF", essentially downloading the HTML of the "view.aspx?id=xxxx" page for every result in the search into a PDF.

Thus I have a loop (for simplicity sake I've hardcoded a loop with the id's):

```
Document doc = pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlString(
    getHtml("{...}View/Default.aspx?id=16480")
);

int id = 16481;
while (id <= 16972) 
{
     doc.AppendDocument(
         pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlString(
             getHtml("{...}View/Default.aspx?id=" + id)
         )
     );
     id++;
     Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

How do I properly take a break between each request? If I do not break the webserver thinks I'm hammering it and kills my session etc. I've seen TONS of Stack overflow posts about not using Thread.Sleep in a web page code-behind, but can't seem to find any of those posts where an alternative is given.

(Note that this is an internal authenticated site, and if you are logged in, you have access to all the ID's, the ID's are a combination of data, not the primary key, thus I don't believe I must worry about the obvious direct object reference)

Comment: Am I right in thinking you're in a legacy webforms environment?

Comment: Webforms asp.net 4 yes. I'll add the tag

Comment: If you're doing so much work that the server doesn't believe you, then you should consider doing that work in a service. You can queue the list of HTML files to the service via WCF. You could even make the web page asynchronous so that you're not blocking the request thread while waiting for the work to be done.

Comment: I thought about using AJAX and storing the document in a session, looping through with javascript (which would make website timeout a non-issue and easily allow an accurate progress bar display) adding one result per javascript call... It would have to postback and Respond the document for download when it was done.

Comment: @DFTR ,still forced into webforms world eh, I feel for you.  I've been out of the webforms loop for a very long time but I'd hope there was a way of rendering a page without making an http request, since you're already on the server right?  This should prevent the session killing.

Comment: Not one that I'm aware of to get the raw full page Html

Comment: Also, I've modified our webforms environment with our own librarys that it's not really that bad anymore to the point I like it just as much as MVC. Though MVC doesn't require that modification.

Comment: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102203-1.2.aspx

Comment: @ChrisMeek - You should answer the question. I've just finished the code and I'm doing a bastardized version of the blog post you put.

Comment: Though I would love to know - for future reference - how to do the proper sleep. For example : How would I do a logarithmic backoff if I'm consuming an external webservice without using thread.sleep?